# Capturing first occurrence of a string between two strings using regex in a column in pyspark dataframe

Tags: regex, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I have a pyspark dataframe (df) which has a date column (data type: str) and a message column (data type str changed from a list object using concat_ws()) as shown below:

**Example dataframe**

```
Date               message
2020-11-01         ['some not required text1', 'Startstring ID :AB_CD', 
                   'some not required text2', 'ID :EDGH', 'some not 
                    required text3', 'ID :XYZ', 'Stopstring' 'some not 
                    required text4', 'Startstring ID :cd_ab', 'some not 
                    required text5', 'ID :ghed', 
                    'some not required text6', ID :zyx', 'Stopstring 'some 
                    not required text7']
2020-11-02         ['some not required text8', Startstring 'ID :ABCD', 
                   'some not required text9', 'ID :ED_GH', 'some not 
                    required text10', ID :X_YZ, Stopstring 'some not 
                    required text11', 'Startstring 
                    ID :cdab', 'some not required text12', 'ID :gh_ed', 
                    'some not required text13', ID :z_yx', 'Stopstring 
                    'some not required text14']
```

I am looking to extract first occurrence of the string just after ID : in between Startstring and Stopstring and discarding the IDs which are not first occurence. There may be multiple such instances in one Date.

**Expected Output:**

```
Date               message
2020-11-01         AB_CD 
2020-11-01         cd_ab
2020-11-02         ABCD 
2020-11-02         cdab
```

**I tried extracting the first occurrence of string just after ID :  as:**

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import *

result = df.withColumn("message", F.regexp_extract(col("message"), r"Startstring[\s\S]*?ID :\s*(\S*)\b[\s\S]*? Stopstring",1))
result.show()
```

It gives me only the string just after ID : for the first time on a particular Date, as shown below:

```
Date               message
2020-11-01         AB_CD 
2020-11-02         ABCD
```

Help in this regard is highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is:

- concatenate the array (as you describe)
- split by "Stopstring"
- explode the column which means that you get a row for each element of the array (and therefore for each occurrence of your pattern)
- apply the regex.

```
df
  .withColumn("concat_message", F.concat_ws(" ",F.col("message")))
  .withColumn("split_message", F.split(F.col("concat_message"), "Stopstring"))
  .withColumn("exploded_message", F.explode(F.col("split_message")))
  .withColumn("parsed_ids", F.regexp_extract(F.col("exploded_message"), r"Startstring[\s\S]*?ID :\s*(\S*)\b[\s\S]*?",1))
  .filter(F.col("parsed_ids") != "")
  .show()
```

One issue is that when splitting by "Stopmessage" this word is removed from the resulting Strings and cannot be used in the Regex pattern.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am getting an error while running this script on databricks.    "org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 100.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.3 in stage 100.0 (TID 1425, 10.139.64.5, executor 17): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 17 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages."

Comment: I got it resolved. your code provides a wrong answer. Thanks

Comment: Your error message sounds like a network issue not a problem with the code ...
If you think that the provided answer is wrong and found a better solution, it might be nice to share it here, for later reference.

Comment: Yes, got that the error was due to the network issue. I got that resolved. However, your code is not generating appropriate output. Anyway, I got the code done by myself.